# Can Selenium test mobile webapps?

Tags: android, selenium, ios-simulator, mobile-safari

I need to test Android (Android Browser) and iPhone/iPad (Safari for iOS) with Selenium or a similar Ruby-aware automated testing tool. How can I do that?

Comment: If you JUST want to change the User-Agent then point your Android browser at http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ or something, and see what it says.

Answer (score 14):

Selenium 2 offers both iphone and android testing, both drivers are pretty experimental as far as I know so YMMV.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver

Comment: are there ruby drivers for that? for capybara for example?

Answer (score 5):

Selenium should be able to handle it:

- For the iPhone, take a look at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver
- For Android, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver

Note that these selenium drivers are still under development, and probably contain bugs.